# useState array type returns undefined instead of empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an issue with my admin dashboard partly I have not done a thing like this before but essentially I am trying to get ready data that ant design graphs will use. This data is coming from mongodb through redux useSelector. Then I map the data and store it in useState of array type

```
  const [data, setdata] = React.useState([]);
  const [reference, setreference] = React.useState([]);
  const [orderActivity, setorderActivity] = React.useState([]);
  const {
    dataStreamMonthly = [],
    user,
    orders = [],
  } = useSelector((state) => state.auth) ?? {};
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getMonthlyRevenue(user.refreshToken));
    dispatch(getOrders(user.refreshToken));
  }, []);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let monthList = [
      "N/A",
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
    ];
    const source =
      dataStreamMonthly &&
      dataStreamMonthly.map((stage) => {
        const monthName = stage._id.month
          ? monthList[parseInt(stage._id.month)]
          : "N/A";
        return { type: monthName, revenue: stage.amount };
      });
    setdata(source);
    
  }, [dataStreamMonthly, orders]);
```

Now the issue is when the component initially renders data is null but that should not be the case since data is an array. So this is where I use it for the graph.

```
const config1 = {
    data,
    xField: "type",
    yField: "revenue",
    color: ({ type }) => {
      return "#ffd333";
    },
    label: {
      // 可手动配置 label 数据标签位置
      position: "middle",
      // 'top', 'bottom', 'middle',
      // 配置样式
      style: {
        fill: "#FFFFFF",
        opacity: 0.6,
      },
    },
    xAxis: {
      label: {
        autoHide: true,
        autoRotate: false,
      },
    },
    meta: {
      type: {
        alias: "Month",
      },
      sales: {
        alias: "Revenue",
      },
    },
  };
```

And subsequently render it

```
<div>
   <Column {...config1} />
</div>
```

I keep getting data is not defined so I conditionally render based on data

```
<div>
   data.length && <Column {...config1} />
</div>
```

Still get the error data is not defined. Please help for I am out of options. **This is a link to the full code** https://dpaste.org/3gRNt

Comment: Where dataStreamMonthly and orders come from. Please add relevant code

Comment: *"Now the issue is when the component initially renders data is null"* With the code shown, `data` definitely will not be `null` on first render. You have `const [data, setdata] = React.useState([]);`, so on first render `data` will definitely be `[]`. (Remember, [`select` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/tips/#:~:text=%E2%80%9Cselect%E2%80%9D%20Isn%27t%20Broken). :-) ) So what you need to do is [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/) to find out why it *seems* like `data` is `null`. More [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within the piece of code where you are trying to set the data here

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    let monthList = [
      "N/A",
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
    ];
    const source =
      dataStreamMonthly &&
      dataStreamMonthly.map((stage) => {
        const monthName = stage._id.month
          ? monthList[parseInt(stage._id.month)]
          : "N/A";
        return { type: monthName, revenue: stage.amount };
      });
    setdata(source);
});
```

when `dataStreamMonthly` resolves to false it return `undefined` you should default it to an empty array by using `|| []` or using a tenary expression instead of the `&&`, this is what I would go for

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    let monthList = [
      "N/A",
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
    ];
    const source =
      dataStreamMonthly ? (
        dataStreamMonthly.map((stage) => {
          const monthName = stage._id.month
            ? monthList[parseInt(stage._id.month)]
            : "N/A";
          return { type: monthName, revenue: stage.amount };
        });
      ) : [];
    setdata(source);
});
```